# Trying to keep double quotes inside the command prompt request from R

Tags: r, cmd, double-quotes

I am going through the number of pdf files with an intention to convert them to text. My script currently looks like this:

```
setwd("test")
dest<-getwd()

#creating vector 

myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)

#removing spaces from file names

sapply(myfiles, FUN = function(i){
  file.rename(from = i, to =  paste0(dirname(i), "/", gsub(" ", "", basename(i))))
})

#recreating vectors to renamed files

myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)

#starting converter

sapply(myfiles, function(i) system2(paste("C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe",i), wait = FALSE))
```

Which results in the following message:

```
Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe C:/Folder/Containing/The Test/Pdf.pdf"' had status 127
```

Which, as to my understanding, is caused by lack of two double quotes in the middle like so:

```
'"C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe**" "**C:/Folder/Containing/The Test/Pdf.pdf"'
```

However, after spending hours online, I cannot find a way of fitting those two double quotes in without breaking the expression completely. The running solutions are either use *cat*, which I cannot do, as I am not trying to output text, or using ANSII, which R quotes directly without transforming it as necessary. Really hoping to find some answers here.

EDIT: the final solution required change in the last line only. The transformed line looks like so:

```
sapply(myfiles, function(i) system2("C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe", args =paste0('"',i,'"',collapse = ""), wait = FALSE))
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in the way `system2` command is used to open the file. Actually the name of the file can be passed as `args` to function `system2`.

The modified code can be:

```
sapply(myfiles, function(i) system2(
     "C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe",
      args = i, wait = FALSE))
```

Comment: Introducing `args` encloses the command in double quotes, but leaves the argument naked. To wrap the argument in double quotes, I had to edit the code to look like following:


 `sapply(myfiles, function(i) system2("C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe", args =paste0('"',i,'"',collapse = ""), wait = FALSE))  `

I will update my original question with the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

`system2` allows you to supply additional arguments that are passed to the system command. The following might work:

```
sapply(myfiles, function(i) system2("C:/Program Files/Wondershare/PDFelement 6 Professional/PDFelement.exe", args = i, wait = FALSE))
```